# How to change use video to confirm word in iOS video recording?

Tags: ios

[image]

We can change of Use Video to Confirm words or other words on iOS video recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible to change the text .Since apple is not providing any methods or API to do that . But you can present a overlay view like below:

```
self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
self.picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
self.picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
self.picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
self.picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Insert the overlay
self.overlay = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overlay" bundle:nil];
self.overlay.pickerReference = self.picker;
self.picker.cameraOverlayView = self.overlay.view;
self.picker.delegate = self.overlay;

[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
```

Design Overlay view as per your requirement. You can also use storyboard to design the overlay view and refer that view controller alone .

Since you haven't mentioned the technology using . I have posted the code in Objective C